# Replacing end few characters of list items?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, replace

I'm trying to replace the last few characters of list items but am unsure how to best do so..

If for example my list is:

```
['44 Example 1/1', '4 Example Here 444/13903', '1 Ex Exam Ple 333/33x']
```

I want to change the `x` on the third one, to an `X` so as shown below:

```
['44 Example 1/1', '4 Example Here 444/13903', '1 Ex Exam Ple 333/33X']
```

---

Another example would be:

```
['44 Example 1/1A', '4 Example Here 444/13903DE', '1 Ex Exam Ple 333/33']
```

Changing `DE` to `dE`:

```
['44 Example 1/1A', '4 Example Here 444/13903dE', '1 Ex Exam Ple 333/33']
```

---

Another example would be:

```
['44 Example 1/1', '4 Example Here 444/13903', '1 Ex Exam Ple 199/1']
```

Changing `199/1` to `1/1`:

```
['44 Example 1/1', '4 Example Here 444/13903', '1 Ex Exam Ple 1/1']
```

I've tried to use a simple `.replace(x, y)` but it goes wrong a lot with the middle parts and sometimes the start.

I do have a regex that I created but still unsure how to do it... `(\S+) (.*?) (\S+)$`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your criteria seems to be different for every list. I don't see how one answer can solve all your  issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$` to match end of string

```
import re
re.sub('DE$', 'dE', '4 Example Here 444/13903DE')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Specifically the `$` symbol to represent the end of a string
You can use `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)`

```
import re
re.sub('x$', 'X', '1 Ex Exam Ple 333/33x')
```

Additionally you can specify count, however since we're using `$` it doesn't matter. Flags are also not required in this case.

Answer (score -1):

I like your first instinct best. Extrapolating from the two examples you posted, you don't have a pattern that is the same for replacing every time? You can reference specific characters with indexes, then change them to what you want.

```
test = ['44 Example 1/1', '4 Example Here 444/13903', '1 Ex Exam Ple 333/33x']
test[2] = test[2][:-1]
```

Notice in line 2 that you can't actually *change* what's in the string, but you can replace the whole string with a new one.

Regex is great at pattern matching, so if you actually need to replace the *same* pattern each time, cool. Like the last 2 letters or whatever. It doesn't seem like you need that for this problem.